# VSCode Output and Terminal using different Python interpreters; one can't find module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**Solution:** I had a sneaky system environment variable that put the 3.10 python variable into the path. Deleted that variable.

I'm super new and trying to import modules like matplotlib to Python. When I hit "run python file", the terminal produces exactly what I want, confirming the import worked. But when I hit "run code" I get the following in the output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Workpls\test.py", line 1, in module
> import matplotlib
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'"

This is the code I ran in both terminal and output:
`import matplotlib`
`help(matplotlib)`

For more context:
It appears I have two python folders of differing versions (v3.9 & v3.10) in my APPDATA/Local/Programs folder. In VSCode I changed everything to the one of interest(v3.9): the vscode default python interpreter path, the interpreter in the blue ribbon at the bottom of vscode, and the command palette Python: Select Interpreter (note that for some reason it still shows v3.10 as the global version in the palette drop down). Yet it still doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: Try to uninstall one/both of the python versions then reinstall. Including reinstalling all libraries

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be related to the confusion of your Python version. I suggest you leave only one Python version, and you can put another version into the virtual environment.

At the same time, we recommend using run Python file. After all, code-runner is not the official extension of Microsoft.